# Как убрать контур у кнопки? Помогите пожалуйста. Python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

root.geometry("600x500")
root.title("Installer ")
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="button.png")


img = PhotoImage(file="D:\Прога для недохакеров\Setup “fozya krya client”.jpg")
b = Label(image=img,bg="gray22")
b.img = ("D:\Прога для недохакеров\Setup “fozya krya client”.jpg")
b.pack(side=TOP,pady=40)

button = Button(
root,
image=image,
relief=SUNKEN,
Border none,
margin= 0,
padding= 0,
command=lambda:
print('click'))\
.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady= 45)
#text_label1 = Label(root,text = "Инсталлер Fozya Krya ", font=("Minecraft Rus", 13), pady= 40, bg="gray22", fg="White")
#text_label1.pack()

root.update()
root["bg"] = "gray22"

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы убрать контур у кнопки, установите `borderwidth` равным нулю:

```
button = Button(
    root,
    image=image,
    relief=SUNKEN,
    borderwidth=0,  
    command=lambda: print('click')
)
```

Comment: Cпасибо, Работает. Можно как то убрать контур у кнопки при нажатии?

Comment: я могу ответить, но вам лучше задать ещё 1 вопрос т.к это в теории поможет другим найти ответ на этот вопрос. Всё же иногда надо думать о потомках)